# What is the difference between Mvvmcross nuget package and Mvvmcross.HotTuna.CrossCore?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

1. What is the difference between Mvvmcross nuget package and Mvvmcross.HotTuna.CrossCore?
2. I built touch project using Mvvmcross.HotTuna.CrossCore and MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries packages. Now It's working well.
   Should I add Mvvmcross nuget package additionally?
3. When I try to add Mvvmcross nuget package, it asks to overwrite Setup.cs file. Should I continue to overwrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) There is no actually any difference between Mvvmcross nuget package and Mvvmcross.HotTuna.CrossCore. Both are associated with each other and is just a package name. You can see if you install anyone of above the result will be the same (just check out version). It will install

```
a) Mvvmcross
b) Mvvmcross - HotTuna Mvvmcross Libraries and
c) Mvvmcross - Hot Tuna Starter Pack
```

Nothing in the name, You can create your own Packages also.

2) No need to add additionally(see section 1). If it prompts you for missing package then you need to install the package.

3) You can overwrite the Setup.cs, LinkerPleaseInclude.cs (IOS) and Main.cs (IOS) if you haven't changed them. Else dont overwrite those files.

You can refer  https://slodge.blogspot.com  for more details and https://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/ for detailed mvvmcross developement

Hopes this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

The MvvmCross assemblies are documented in the documentation here: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/getting-started/mvvmcross-packages

The NuGet packages roughly follow those same assembly divisions.

Both the starter pack and the MvvmCross wrapper nuget packages both provide easy getting started content files like setup.cs. If you're an advanced user and don't need setup.cs, then you don't need to use these NuGet packages - you can use the MvvmCross libraries package instead.

Comment: If I added Mvvmcross nuget package, then no need to add HotTuna start pack?